# It was or It were school holidays

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I read this sentence: "It was school holidays, and they were going to spend a whole week there."
I cannot understand why it is "It was school holidays..." Why not "It were school holidays..."?
Is it because "it" is singular and takes singular verb "was"?

Comment: Also related, but not a duplicate:  [“It was Bob and Tom” – why not “They were”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/181732/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. The subject is *it*, which is singular.